# Wordpress is not just digesting! Suggest me a best vedio for full comprehension of wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Actually I have started learning Wordpress. And I am not understanding at all. Kindly dear developers, suggest me a best vedio which helps me understand wordpress from scratch.A full vedio on that.

Comment: WordPress first of all its a CMS(Content management System) you must know that, it's used to give solutions to customers that want to manage their content in their web apps. normally its used for bloggers and ecommerces. By this what exactly want to know about WordPress?

Comment: I want to develop a complete Website of College? How should I start in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

You chose WordPress because you wanted to skip a lot of code, then I recommend you to buy a theme in https://themeforest.net/, verify that has good reviews, more than 500 sells. after that they have good documentation of how it works.

Choose any of the best seller too: https://themeforest.net/collections/6987239-best-selling-themes-of-all-time-on-themeforest

for any tutorial you can choose any in [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how%20to%20do%20a%20website%20with%20premium%20theme), find anyone with more than one million views. verify that use the same components of the theme that you want to use. (page builders like elementor, divi or WPBakery).